# Convert a PHP array to an SQL statment?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to convert an array (key/value) to be an SQL statement.

I'm using MYSQLi like such:

```
if(!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)){throw new Exception("SQL Failed ".__file__." on line ".__line__.":\n".$sql);}
```

I have an array like such:

```
Array
(
[database] => Array
    (
        [cms_network] => Array
            (
                [network_id] => 61
                [network_name] =>
                [network_server_mac_address] => 00:1b:eb:21:38:f4
                [network_description] => network
                [network_thermostat_reporting_rate] => 5
                [network_server_reporting_rate] => 5
                [network_data_poll_rate] => 5
                [network_created_by] => 38
                [network_modified_by] => 1
                [network_network_id] => 8012
                [network_language] => en
                [network_hotel_id] => 68
                [network_channel] => 0
                [network_deleted] => 0
                [network_reported_network_id] => 8012
                [network_rooms] => 4
            )

    )

)
```

How can I convert [cms_network] to look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE cms_network set network_id='61', network_name='',      
network_server_mac_address = '00:1b:eb:21:38:f4', .... WHERE network_id='61'"
```

I'm more interested in knowing how to concatenate the `key=>value` pair of the array to be `key='value'` in my select statement.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: assuming that you set the inline array to the variable `$cms_network`, you can use `foreach ($cms_network as $key=>$value) {}` and build your query string.

Comment: I'd like to use implode() but  I can't figure out how to blend the values in with the keys. When imploding the array, I only get the values: 61,,00:1b:eb:21:38:f4,network,5,5,5,38,1,8012,en,68,0,0,8012,4. I would need to implode the keys as well and map them together somehow.

Comment: `implode()` doesn't do associative array. You could use `array_walk()` but that would be an overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the VALUES syntax, you could do it in one fell swoop.

```
mysql_query("
UPDATE MyTable
( . implode(',', array_keys($array['database']['cms_network'])) . ")
VALUES ('" . implode("','", $array['database']['cms_network']) . "')
");
```

This, of course, assumes that the data is already escaped.

**EDIT:** Tidier version that's easier to read and maintain:

```
$fields = implode(',', array_keys($array['database']['cms_network']));
$values = implode("','", $array['database']['cms_network']);
mysql_query("UPDATE MyTable ($fields) VALUES ('$values')");
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to simplify using implode ! all my data is already controlled since it comes from another Database on another server (which has it's data protected). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you populate an array with formatted key/value pairs, then implode them at the end. This is an easy way to add the required `,` between each key/value:

```
$fields = array();
foreach($array['database']['cms_network'] as $key => $value) {
    // add formatted key/value pair to fields array
    // e.g. format: network_id = '26'
    $fields[] = $key . " = '" . $value . "'";
}
$fields = implode(', ', $fields);
// build your query
$query = "UPDATE cms_network SET " . $fields . " WHERE network_id = " . $array['database']['cms_network']['network_id'] . " LIMIT 1";
// process it...
```

This will (SQL wise) be inserting every value as a **string**, which is obviously incorrect with integer columns etc. It should still work anyway, but if not you'll need to put in a conditional statement for whether to wrap the value in quotes or not, [like this](https://www.php.net/is_numeric):

```
foreach(...) {
    if(is_numeric($value))
        $fields[] = $key . ' = ' . $value;
    else
        $fields[] = $key . " = '$value'";
}
```

Although this should probably relate to your **database column type** rather than the PHP variable type. Up to you, they should work fine with quotes around integers.

Comment: It worth to mention that you need to escape the string values properly, in this case with `mysql_real_escape_string`, otherwise you cannot guarantee the query to be syntactically correct

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$update_query = "UPDATE `cms_network` SET ";
$count = 0;
foreach($array['database']['cms_network'] as $key => $value)    {
    if ($count != 0)    {
        $update_query = $update_query.",".$key."=".$value;
    }   else    {
        $update_query = $update_query.$key."=".$value;
    }
    $count++;
}
$update_query = $update_query." WHERE ".cms_network."=".$array['database']['cms_network'];
mysql_query($update_query);
```

Comment: It will generate something like `network_server_mac_address=00:1b:eb:21:38:f4` which is not a valid statement

Comment: He can fix it on his own with implode, explode or anyway he want to insert this data.

Comment: It won't :) sorry got mistaken with another function.